# <SelectInput>: how to populate choices depending on record data in Edit component of react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

I need to show different  choices based on record's field value.

The code for my needs looks like this:

```js
const myChoicesGenerator = (record) => {
    if (record.field === false) {
      return ['a', 'b'];
    } else {
      return ['b', 'c'];
    }

<SelectInput ... choices = {myChoicesGenerator}/>
```

But unfortunately i can't pass functions in "choices" property, so this code doesn't work.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a `<FormDataConsumer />` to get the current record and pass it to your function.

```
<FormDataConsumer>
    {
        ({formData, ...rest}) =>
            <SelectInput 
                 choices={myChoiceGenerator(formData)}
                 {...rest}
            />
    }
</FormDataConsumer>
```

Doc: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs

I dont' know if the values `['a', 'b']` are valid for `<SelectInput />`. Consider using a list of tuples (`id`, `name`) as described in the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#selectinput).

Comment: yes, it works, and don't forget the **source** prop on <SelectInput/>

Comment: What if the `choices` should come from the server? Choices is not `async`, so how can we do this?

Comment: @user2078023 You can use `<ReferenceInput />` to load your choices from the server. (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#referenceinput)